# Cloud9: Request not allowed from http://localhost:13339

Tags: macos, cloud9-ide

Some time ago I installed Cloud9 local IDE on my Mac/OSX. After starting the app when trying logging in I get "Request not allowed from localhost:13339"! Is there a solution for this problem or otherwise I would like un-installing the app on my Mac; can I just move the app to my trash or are there hidden files left that way?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to detail how you launched Cloud9 (what the command was you used to launch it, which version of Node you were using, and in which directory you were when you launched it)?

Comment: I launch Cloud9 in my /Applications (/Applications/Cloud9 IDE.app) folder. The app I installed, in March this year, was an *.dmg file (so an install file).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thread of discussion on Github that may be relevant to the OS X .dmg installer you used.  It includes a link to what appears to be the latest installer, but the conversation is still dated for two years ago.

https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/issues/1770

An alternative means of installing and running it is by installing from source directly from Github:

http://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9

Note the installation instructions on the Wiki.  As of the date of this post, I found that I could run Cloud9 from the source on my local machine if:

1. Ensured I was running the latest version of Node v0.10
2. Made sure I had installed Mercurial as the Node defaults expect it to be available (I used brew like so, "brew install mercurial")
3. Then ran the installation script from the cloud9 source directory "npm install"
4. Before launching it ensured I was actually IN the cloud9 source directory when I ran it.  So, for example, if I wanted to edit a project in another directory I would launch it:

   `./bin/cloud9.sh -w ../path/to/other/project`
5. It will inform you of the address at which you can access it (with the parameters above you'd access it at the default of localhost:3131)
6. You may get a "Session ID" error when you access it.  If so, simply refresh your browser.

This method worked for me.  It was very much a trial and error process (not very smooth at all.)  I wasn't aware of the "app", however, by using the direct source my hope is to have a more current install (easily updated with `git pull`).  Here are some other links containing information that I found useful in debugging my installation.  Unfortunately the Cloud9 installation process is not for the faint hearted and does not list all the libraries and binaries required for the default installation:

- https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/issues/2741

  - Information on needing to have Mercurial (hg) installed
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1813076

  - More Linux related, but still helpful in considering all the prerequisites.